# Jsoup: "parentTag > childTag" matches, but "parentTag childTag" gives nothing

Tags: java, jquery, jsoup

**EDIT**: seems to be a bug in 1.8.3, it works as expected in 1.11.2 .

I'm trying to parse an html document using jsoup 1.8.3 from Java. I don't understand the behavior of some selectors (they are supposed to be similar to jQuery selectors).

Consider the following minimal example (it is supposed to select code snippets from a StackOverflow question):

```
package edu.example;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407833").get();
        Element question = doc.select("div#question div.post-text").first();
        Elements allChildren = question.children();
        Elements codeSnippets = allChildren.select("pre > code");
        System.out.println("code snippets start-----");
        System.out.println(codeSnippets);
        System.out.println("/code snippets end -----");
    }
}
```

What I don't understand: if I replace `pre > code` by `pre code`, then the list of selected elements is empty. Why does this happen?

If I understand this page: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax correctly, then

- `ancestor descendant` selects all elements with tag `descendant` which descend from an element with tag `ancestor`
- `parent > child` selects all elements with tag `child` which descend directly from an element with tag `parent`

The parent-child relationship is a special case of ancestor-descendant relationship (ancestor-descendant relation is the transitive closure of the parent-child relation) . How is it possible that the first selector does not match strictly more tags than the second selector?

Here is an excerpt of the relevant HTML that you would see if you clicked on "view page source":

```
<div class="question" data-questionid="48407833"  id="question">
   ...
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
       ...
       <pre><code>package edu.example;
       ...
```

*PS:* if you want to quickly build a little project and try it out, here's a minimal `pom.xml` for Maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoupselectorquestion</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jsoupselectorquestion</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: If you update jsoup to the current release version, which is 1.11.2. both selectors have the same result. Might have been a bug in older versions.

Comment: I'll check this immediately.

Comment: @Eritrean oh, well... This was an easy one. Indeed, it works with 1.11.2 as expected. Must be a bug in 1.8. How did I come up with 1.8 anyway. Thank you. You can make it into an answer, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was a bug in 1.8. Use a more actual version, e.g. 1.11.2 instead.